# Vue scroll div to top inside method

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, vue-component

Learning Vue. Trying to get a chat window div to scroll to the top when a new chat entry is found.

My Vue component is:

```
const app = new Vue({ 
    el: '#toolbar-chat',

    data: {
        messages: []
    },

    created() {
        this.fetchMessages();

        Echo.private(chat_channel)
            .listen('ChatMessageSent', (e) => {
                this.messages.unshift({
                    message: e.data.message,
                    player: e.data.player.nickname
                });
            });
    },

    methods: {
        fetchMessages() {
            axios.get(chat_get_route)
                .then(response => {
                    this.messages = response.data;
                });
        },

        addMessage(message) {
            this.messages.unshift(message);

            this.$nextTick(() => {
                this.$refs.msgContainer.scrollTop = 0;
            });

            axios.post(chat_send_route, message)
                .then(response => {
                    console.log(response.data);
                });

        }
    }
});
```

My chat message Template

```
<template>
    <div ref="msgContainer" class="toolbar-chat">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12" v-for="message in messages">
                <strong class="primary-font">
                    {{ message.player.nickname }}:
                </strong>
                {{ message.message }}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        props: ['messages']
    };
</script>
```

My chat send template

```
<template>
    <div class="input-group input-group-sm">
        <input id="btn-input" type="text" class="form-control" value="" required="required"  maxlength="140" placeholder="Type your message here..." v-model="newMessage" @keyup.enter="sendMessage">
        <div class="input-group-btn">
            <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button"  id="btn-chat" @click="sendMessage">
                <i class="fa fa-paper-plane"></i>
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        props: ['player'],

        data() {
            return {
                newMessage: ''
            }
        },

        methods: {
            sendMessage() {
                this.$emit('chatmessagesent', {
                    player: this.player,
                    message: this.newMessage
                });

                this.newMessage = ''
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

And in my page I include the templates

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-md-4" id="toolbar-chat">
    <chat-messages :messages="messages"></chat-messages>
    <chat-form v-on:chatmessagesent="addMessage" :player="{{ Auth::user() }}"></chat-form>
</div>
```

A message adds to the list OK, but I get this error:

> [Vue warn]: Error in nextTick: "TypeError: Cannot set property 'scrollTop' of undefined"

Is it the way the element is named (camelCase)? What have I missed.

Comment: What does the template look like? `$refs` only refers to child elements with a `ref` attribute. If you want the root element (ie `#toolbar-chat`), use `this.$el`

Comment: Hi @Phil, thanks for the response. I updated my Q with all the pieces. I will look at your suggestion

Comment: So which `div` is it you want to scroll?

Comment: Sorry @Phil, based on your reply before I updated above. I added a `ref="msgContainer"` and call it in `$nextTick`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the element you want to scroll is within a component, you should implement a method on that component that you can call.

For example, in your `chat-messages` component...

```
methods: {
  scrollToTop () {
    this.$el.scrollTop = 0
  }
}
```

and in your Vue instance, add a `ref` for that component...

```
<chat-messages ref="messages"...
```

and in the `addMessage` method...

```
this.$refs.messages.scrollToTop()
```

Comment: This doesn't work - `this.$refs.messageHolder.scrollDown() is not a function`.

Comment: @Peter considering my answer does not have a "scrollDown" method, I'm not surprised. You should open a new question

Comment: Ah, well let me clarify. With your code example this.$refs.messageHolder.scrollToTop() does not appear to work (I had a different function name, but otherwise the same). Don't worry about it though, I found an alternative solution. Thanks!

Comment: @PeterWeyand that might be because the `ref` in my answer is `messages`, not `messageHolder`. It also needs to be a component and not a regular HTML element in order to expose methods

Comment: @PeterWeyand without any other context (such as your actual code), your comments aren't adding anything to this post. Since comments are not the place for code, you should really open a new question.

Answer (score 1):

We can use [scrollIntoView()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView) method for such purpose, e.g:

```
this.$refs.yourRef.$el.scrollIntoView();
```